# How do i convert Strings.Format from vb to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, format

Does anyone know how to convert this vb Strings.Format code into its equivalent c# code?  Or is there a way to use this vb code in a c# file?

```
lblWait.Text = "Please Wait, Generating Art Cache... " & Format((ID / 65535) * 100, "Fixed") & "%
```

** Edit ok I added a reference to my project for Microsoft.VisualBasic then added a using statement and that allows me to use that string in my c# code but is there a c# equivalent?

** Edit replaced coverted code with original vb code, sorry about that... :)

roadmaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string formatted = (ID*100.0/65535).ToString("f1") + "%";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
          string.Format(Math.Round((ID / 65535f) * 100, 1) + "%");
```

A better way to do this is

```
          var result =  Math.Round((ID  / 65535f) * 100, 1).ToString("f1") + "%";
```

Comment: Also: ID/65535 will always be 0 if ID is an integer < 65535

Comment: In the VB code, the integer division operator is '\' - since this wasn't used, it's a mistake to add 'Math.Round' in the conversion.

Comment: @DrKoch: Only if using \.  `ID/65535f` will return a floating point value. @Dave Doknjas: `Math.Round` is ok here but unnecessary.  If ID is, for example 100, `ID/65535f` will be `.0015259..`.  He multiplies that by 100 and then rounds to one decimal place. This will give .2.  Of course, `(.00152..).ToString("f1")` will do this for you, so it's just redundant.

Comment: @dwilliss at the time I wrote my comment it was ID/65535 (without the 'f') and this is an integer division in C# returning 0 for ID < 65535

Comment: @DrKoch: oh, that makes sense.  I was thinking VB.NET, not C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = (ID / 65535f).ToString("P1");
```